# How can I able to display following using vue js?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vue-component

My `JSON` is:

```
[{
  "name": "Health care",
  "cat_id": 1
}, {
  "name": "Education",
  "cat_id": 2
}, {
  "name": "Bakery",
  "cat_id": 3
}, {
  "name": "Software company",
  "cat_id": 4
}]
```

My vue js script is.

```
<script>
  new Vue({
  el: '#categories' ,
  data: {
    articles: [],
  },
  mounted() {
    this.$nextTick(function() {
      var self = this;
      $.ajax({
            url: "https://",
            method: "GET",
            dataType: "JSON",
            success: function (e) {

                    self.articles = e.articles;
                    console.log(e.articles)

            },
        });
    })
  },

})

</script>
```

The html code used is

```
<div v-for="post in articles" id="categories">
                <div class="top">
                    <h4>Top Categories</h4>
                    <ul class="mov_list">
                        <li><i class="fa fa-star"></i></li>
                        <li>77</li>
                        <li><a href="">{{post.name}}</a></li>
                    </ul>   
                </div>
      </div>
```

This is where I am trying to display the different categories. But I am getting some errors. Can anybody please help me to display the same. I am weak in js

Comment: Can you paste also the errors you are getting please ?

Comment: Please provide more relevant information like: what is the output, what kind of errors you're getting, etc.

Comment: I am not able to print anything

Comment: Do you know how to use developer tools on a desktop browser? In most browsers, right-click and Inspect, look for a Console tab.

Comment: There is no error in that

Comment: jquery.min.js:4 XHR finished loading: GET "https://n2s.herokuapp.com/api/post/get_all_category/".

Comment: Everything looks fine for me. I am getting the data response. But when I use the above code it is not displaying. I am using vue js code as above

Comment: hello sir, can you please help me

Comment: The api you are calling does not give back a `articles` key inside the final json, this causes your code to fail

Comment: so, how can i able to correct it sir

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a scope issue. `self` has to be declared outside of the function. Still I believe you do not need to specify the callback. Something like this should be sufficient:

```
<script>
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        articles: [],
    },
    mounted() {
        var self = this;

        $.ajax({
            url: "https://n2s.herokuapp.com/api/post/get_all_category/",
            method: "GET",
            dataType: "JSON",
            success: function(e) {
                self.articles = e.articles;
                console.log(e.articles)
            },
        });
    },
})
</script>
```

html:

```
<div id="app">
    <div v-for="post in articles">
        <div class="top">
            <h4>Top Categories</h4>
            <ul class="mov_list">
                <li><i class="fa fa-star"></i></li>
                <li>77</li>
                <li><a href="">{{post.name}}</a></li>
            </ul>   
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Cheers!

Comment: The message is receive is `Cannot use v-for on stateful component root element because it renders multiple elements.`. So you have to wrap your html code in something like `<div id="app">` and also change the `el` key to `#app` in the vue root instance.